# how to avoid browser sniffing by doing "feature" detection instead...?

Tags: cross-browser, browser-detection

So, let's say that I have an element that is inline-block.  So this won't work with ie6 or FF2...

Say I compensate for it with css hacks and using -moz-inline-stack...

Now, let's say the inline-block element is also position: relative, so it is a container and has a child element with position absolute, top:0, right: 0.

In older browsers, the child element is in the top right of the screen, instead of in the top right of the inline-block container element...

Now, I can fix this by wrapping a div around my child element and make it 'position relative'...  But I would like to avoid having unnecessary markup if possible.

Initially I wanted to do:

```
if (browser == ie6 || browser == ff2) {
  wrap child element with div for older browser..
} 
else {
  assume everything is fine
}
```

but I am thinking something like this would be better to do:

```
if (child element is at the top right of the screen) {
  wrap child element with div for older browser..
} 
else {
  assume everything is fine
}
```

So I am just curious, how people here would recommend this sort of thing.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general, [Modernizr](http://www.modernizr.com/) does browser feature detection best. Modernizr

> adds classes to the  element
>   which allow you to target specific
>   browser functionality in your
>   stylesheet. You don't actually need to
>   write any Javascript to use it.

While it may not be applicable to your particular scenario, Modernizr does CSS feature detection as well. For example,

> Have you ever wanted to do
>   if-statements in your CSS for the
>   availability of cool features like
>   border-radius? Well, with Modernizr
>   you can accomplish just that!